# Adding class styles on summernote's toolbar

Tags: css, class, summernote

I want to change the styles on Summernote tools bar.Do you know how to add my class styles on it?

Comment: Do you mean the icons from the toolbar on the site http://summernote.org/#/ ?

Comment: Yes. On Summernote's toolbar is possible select this tags: "p", "blockquote", "pre", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6".  But,  I want select text and then select some class to work on it.  Example: I have created in my proyect the class "myHeadLines", I wish select any text on summernote and then apply this class.

Comment: Ah now I understand. I believe you can't add your own custom classes to the code that you written in Summernote. What you can do is click the `Code view` button and start writing your HTML code with the classes you prefer.

Comment: Yes, of course Bas.  I'm shure I can do it. But the idea is that any person who writes on Summernote can do it easily, because maybe he dont know about HTML.

Comment: Oh, like that. But  where does he get the CSS classes from then?

Comment: My idea is write some class styles for Summernote takes. But, I dont know where.
The other posibility is add new icon on tool bar to do it. But, I neither know it.